# How to use Observables/ real-time change only one entry in table in angular2+

Tags: html, angular

I am stuck with an issue in angular4 and node.js app. I display the data in a table that has 7 columns via *ngFor . Now the issue is , i need to dynamically and on real-time basis update the last column . i.e. if the column -> Active ... is Yes , then i display a green color and when the Active ...is No, then i display a red color. But then i am not sure how to update the last column and only the last column real-time.

[1]
I thought of using Observables code in init from where i call the table data, but that will only keep on showing the loader always , as the data will keep on uploading regularly after a few seconds and disturb the entire table view.

[2]
And i have shown the color based on an if condition, but in all the entries, it shows only green color.

code -

**interface.component.ts**

```
 export class MasterInterfaceComponent implements OnInit {

  activeCheck;
   activeValue;
   activeRedColor;
    activeGreenColor;


   ngOnInit() {

    console.log("beginning of func");

   Observable.interval(15000).subscribe(x => {
    console.log("Called")
    this.viewData();
    });


   }


   viewData() {

     this.loading = true;
     var url = config.url;
    var port = config.port;
    this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" ...... ('Token') }) })
   .map(result => this.result = result.json(),

      )
     .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    this.loading = false;
    this.records = res;
    console.log("xxxx interface view result data ",this.result)
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXX  interface view res data ", res);

    this.activeCheck = this.result;

    for (let obj of this.activeCheck){
    for (let key in obj){

      if (key == "ACTIVE_YN"){

         if (obj[key] == "Y"){
           this.activeRedColor = false;
           this.activeGreenColor = true;

           console.log("this.activeGreenColor = true;");
         }

         else if (obj[key] == "N"){
          this.activeRedColor = true;
          this.activeGreenColor = false;

          console.log("this.activeGreenColor = false;");
         }
         }
       }
      }

     });


   }
```

**interface.component.html**

```
 <tbody>

   <tr *ngFor="let data of result |filter:filter| orderBy : 'IF_ID'|
              paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i =      

    index">
    <td class="text-center" style="width:8%">
      <a [hidden]= "accessIdHide" [routerLink]="['/master-system/update-  
         interface']" (click)="forUpdate(data)" data-toggle="tooltip" 
      title="Update" style="color:#ffffff;;float:left"
        type="link">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>

    </a>{{data.IF_ID}}
    </td>
    <td>{{data.IF_CD}}</td>
    <td>{{data.IF_NAME}}</td>
    <td>{{data.IF_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
    <td>{{data.SRC_SYS_NAME}}</td>
    <td>{{data.TRGT_SYS_NAME}}</td>
    <td >

       <img [hidden]= "activeGreenColor" src = "url" width="10" height =        
     "10">{{data.ACTIVE_YN}}
      <img  [hidden] = "activeRedColor" src = "url" width="10" height = 
      "10">{{data.ACTIVE_YN}}
      </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not need two switches, but the way you had it is ok, but for our discussion, let's just say we have one switch "isActive".

I think your code should work, but you need to make sure the subscription is firing, ex.

```
.subscribe((res: Response) => {
    console.log(res);
```

If this code fires every time the data changes, then your `img` should be turned on and off

```
<img *ngIf="isActive" src="url">
```

or

```
<img [ngClass]="{ isActive: green }">
```

Either of the above is fine. So just try to debug your observable to work the way you wanted, ex. when it should be fired and in which frequency.

Comment: is there any way that only the "Active" column in the for-loop has the observable as it is the only changing entity

Comment: absolutely you can, but you need to have a separate observable handling the flag change, ex. `flag$ = new Observable<boolean>(false)`. Once you have this new variable, then you can do `<img *ngIf="flag$ | async">` in the template. Just an idea.